# When a VirtualBox VM's Adapter is set to Internal Network does the VM have Access to the Outside Network of the host?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, adapter

In a VMs network settings:

1. Right click settings,
2. then in the resulting Settings dialog select `Network` from the side bar
3. And click any `Adapter N` tab,
4. If I set the `Attached to:` drop down to `Internal Network`

Will the VM be able to access the external network?  Or will I need another adapter type for that that will cause the vm to function as a gateway of some sort?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this was off topic; can you please move this to super user?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal network only has access to VMs on the same host.

"Internal Networking is similar to bridged networking in that the VM can directly communicate with the outside world. However, the "outside world" is limited to other VMs on the same host which connect to the same internal network."

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal